# How to compile a project in Eclipse that uses subfolders?

Tags: c++, eclipse, include

I'm trying to compile two folders in eclipse from a large open source project which is compiled by make. I have two folders opencog/server and opencog/atomspace. The problem is that the includes refer to the subfolders in the large project

e.g. #include "opencog/server/Factory.h" instead of #include "Factory.h"

so eclipse looks for opencog/server/opencog/server/Factory.h instead of opencog/server/Factory.h

Is there any way to solve this without changing the includes?

Thanks

Comment: Which language? Add appropriate tag for language to get answers.

Comment: @KuldeepJain The program is written in C++

Comment: Yeah, but for anyone to even open the question, the correct tag should be present. Like here, as soon as you added the C++ tag, you got the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `myfolder/opencog/server` then add `myfolder` to the include search paths.

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't seem to work
g++ -I~/ocserver -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"opencog/server/Agent.d" -MT"opencog/server/Agent.d" -o "opencog/server/Agent.o" "../opencog/server/Agent.cc"
In file included from ../opencog/server/Agent.cc:25:0:
../opencog/server/Agent.h:30:36: fatal error: opencog/server/Factory.h: No such file or directory

Comment: @ErwinJ. Perhaps try the full path, rather than `~/`. Optionally, try relative to your cwd.

Comment: Putting the full path did it. Thanks a lot.